# In Fireworks CS5, How to hide all fills/strokes and show only paths (wire view)?

Tags: adobe-fireworks, visualization

I have a complex vector graphic with overlapped shapes and I've been looking for a View mode that allows me to see only the paths. I guess it's called wire view or path view, but I can't find that option.

Comment: I don't understand why they removed the outline view mode (CMD+K) which was really useful! If you work heavily on FW you definetely need that feature. Any idea on how to have a similar view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alan is right that there is no such view but there is a way to do it. I usually just use the sub-selection tool (white arrow) and click and drag (a black box appears) around the vector object(s) to show up all the paths.

Answer (score 2):

The Outline view was removed in version Fireworks CS5. Previous version of Fireworks has keyboard command ctrl+k to switch Outline-mode on and off.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for something analogous to Illustrator's Outline View. Fireworks doesn't have such a feature as far as I know or can discover. (I've never looked for it and I've also never come across mention of it. Couldn't find any reference to an outline or wire view in any of the sources I have at my disposal in a half hour of digging. FW isn't a program I use heavily, so I was hoping someone with deeper knowledge than mine would chip in.